# Selenium Webdriver - Login popup appears only on webdriver

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am creating a test with selenium webdriver using C#.
I am navigating to a web page, when i open this page manually in firefox or chrome, it goes directly to the page's content.

When the webdriver navigates to the URL of the page, a login popup appears which i cannot handle with the Webdriver. I have tried the Switchto().Alert() method but it is not working because the browser keeps loading in the backgroung waiting for the user action.

When i cancel the popup manually, the webdriver navigates correctly to the URL.

What i think is the problem, is that there is a difference between the firefox profile used by Webdriver & the default profile i am using.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: You could clone the profile and use it with selenium

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Switch to Alert?  Likely it is simply html page.
And I think that if you will logout from your site and try to go there again, you will see this login form.

Answer (score 0):

```
string jQuerySelector = "className"+"TagName:has(tagName:contains(Name_of_Element))";
string findAppointment = "return $(\"" + jQuerySelector + "\").get(0);";
WebElement ChooseAppointment = (WebElement) js.executeScript(findAppointment);
ChooseAppointment.Click(); (Example -->)

string jQuerySelector=".quickadd"+"li:has(a:contains('Appointment'))";
string findAppointment = "return $(\"" + jQuerySelector + "\").get(0);";
WebElement ChooseAppointment = (WebElement) js.executeScript(findAppointment);
ChooseAppointment.Click
```